# Node.js - package.json does not exist in user dir

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, node-red

I do have a /home/pi/.node-red/package.json but not where npm expected it at
/home/pi/package.json
so a

`npm install` or any other install of any node causes the follwing error

```
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/pi/package.json' 
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/pi/package.json' 
npm WARN pi No description 
npm WARN pi No repository field.
npm WARN pi No README data 
npm WARN pi No license field.
```

when I check the location it is claiming, the error is correct. There is nothing it expectes. The question is how to solve this?

Does a symlink into the uses home be ok or do you have any other recommandation. 
A "npm install", "npm cache clean" and a "sudo npm install -g npm" has not resolved this issue.

I run
node -v
v8.11.1
on my Rapsberry PI with
Linux 4.14.52+ arm LE

This seems to be the latest version as a :
`curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo -E bash -`

```
## Installing the NodeSource Node.js 10.x repo...
```

`## You appear to be running on ARMv6 hardware. Unfortunately this is not currently supported by the NodeSource Linux distributions. Please use the 'linux-armv6l' binary tarballs available directly from nodejs.org for Node.js 4 and later.`

Comment: Hi - your question does not actually say what you are doing. Please provide some more details as to what you're doing and what commands you are running.

Comment: The implication from the message is that you are running npm in `/home/pi` not in `/home/pi/.node-red`. Also have you tried using the Node-RED install script as it will install/upgrade NodeJS for you as part of the install.

Comment: You still haven't explained what you are trying to achieve

Comment: are you refering to:  bash <(curl -sL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/node-red/raspbian-deb-package/master/resources/update-nodejs-and-nodered)

Comment: I am trying to install npm nodes with node install <node name>

Comment: when I do a cd /home/pi/.node-red and try a install I do not get the errors mentioned above npm install node-red-contrib-sonoff-server
npm WARN node-red-project@0.0.1 No repository field.
npm WARN node-red-project@0.0.1 No license field.

+ node-red-contrib-sonoff-server@1.0.0
updated 1 package and audited 1737 packages in 110.833s
found 45 vulnerabilities (14 low, 15 moderate, 16 high)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

Comment: Don't use the comments to post extra info - update your question.

Comment: What you have posted looks like a successful install, with a couple warnings that are only warnings, not errors

Answer (score 0):

To create a package.json in any directory, you can call the `npm init` command. This will prompt some basic questions and after answering them, a new package.json file will be created. Then you can do `npm install`.

You can also create a new package.json file manually.

However in your case, it seems you don't need to have a package.json (for node-red).
You can install node-red globally with the following command. (assuming you are using linux)

```
sudo npm install -g node-red
```

then run it with

```
node-red
```